# using javax.mail to send message

Tags: java, email

I would like to send an email using javax.mail from example@uni.ac.uk to receiver@uni.ac.uk. I have tried the below code but it gives error which i also put below. Any help is welcome.

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Session sess = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop,null);

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(sess);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("example@uni.ac.uk", "Sender"));
             msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                      new InternetAddress("receiver@uni.ac.uk", "Receiver"));
            msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
            msg.setText("Testing messgage");
           Transport.send(msg);


}
```

Error generated is

> `Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to
>
>             SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
>             nested exception is:
>          java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
>          at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1962)
>          at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
>          at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
>          at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
>          at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
>          at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
>          at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
>          at MAIL.sendmail.main(sendmail.java:41)
>              Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
>          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>          at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
>          at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
>          at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1928)
>          ... 7 more`

Answer (score 1):

Here an example properties to send email using gmail:

```
private Properties createConfiguration() {
    return new Properties() {{
        put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the SMTP server in the Properties object to your own machine (localhost), that is obviously not running an SMTP server on port 25. I think you want to use an existing SMTP server (like the one you get from your internet provider, or the one that GMail offers you, etc...).

Comment: Yes i would like to user gmail